# How to allow only cell resizing but cannot change data in excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, read-only

In one of my lotusscript code, I output some data to excel. Initially I only allow the user to print and not make any changes to the spreadsheet. But then the user request that they want to resize the cell, adjust height etc before printing and that these changes can be saved. But I don't want them to change the data inside. Is that possible? If I set the whole excel file as read-only then the user won't be allowed to save any changes at all including the cell resizing.

Comment: How are you creating the excel file? What is the code to do so? Do you want this to occur as it is created? Do you want to go into each file and make this happen?

Comment: I create a an excel file without data but only some titles, header etc (consider this a template). This template is the store into the database. The lotusscript code will extract the excel template when it is needed and populate data into it. Once it's done, it'll popup to the user. For now I already set so that the user can't do anything except print it. But now they want to at least resize the cell etc because when it came out it won't be properly aligned etc. But I don't want the data to compromise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unlock the sheet and Throw this into the VBA and run it. It will do what you're looking for for the activesheet. Replace "Password" with your password.

```
sub baxter()
ActiveSheet.Protect "Password", AllowFormattingRows:=True, AllowFormattingColumns:=True
end sub
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need code to accomplish this. When you click to Protect the worksheet there will be a drop down with a list of items you can allow. Click format columns and rows.